# browser opens .ini file as video (media)

Tags: apache, mime-types, twiki

I'm running a TWiki-Web on Apache in our local network.
Whenever I try to download an attached .ini-File, the browser (I tried several) tries to open it as some kind of media starting a video-player.
I'm a bit stuck here. I want the browser to thread the file as text but I don't know if this ist some configuration I have to do in my local browser, in the TWiki-System or at the webserver?
When I try to "Save link as..." opera will download the file correctly as .ini but Firefox wants to add a "mp3"-Extension instead of .ini

Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: change your default action on your computer sections to open it with notepad, or another text editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit Apache Configurations

1. run

`sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

2. then add

`AddType text/plain .ini`

3. then close and save and restart your server

`sudo service httpd restart`

Comment: had to restart httpd instead of apache2 but it worked like a charme. thank you